# How to prevent "Cannot read property example of undefined" when trying to check if said property is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Im writing a simple Discord bot on node.js with discord.js using JSON as a database (i know i probably shouldn't use JSON for a database but i dont want to setup an actual database right now) that has a single command, "!click". When you do "!click" in a guild, it will check if your discord id has any clicks in the database, and if you dont have any your clicks value is set to  1, if you do then your clicks+=1. The problem I have is when checking if the user has `undefined` clicks. When checking by using `if(data[personid].clicks === undefined)` I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'MyDiscordId' of undefined`. What can I do to fix this? Here is my full code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
var fs = require("fs");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
    if (!msg.guild) return;
  if (msg.content === '!click') {
      msg.reply("Your clicks is now "+ clickeridoo(msg.author.id))
  }
});
function clickeridoo(idd){
    var json = ""
    var data;
    var playerid = idd.toString();
    fs.readFile("data.json", function(err, data){
        json = JSON.stringify(data);
        data = JSON.parse(json);
    })
    if(data[playerid].clicks === undefined){
        data[playerid].clicks=1;
    }else{
        if(data[playerid].clicks !== undefined){
            data[playerid].clicks+=1;
        }
    }
    fs.writeFile("data.json", data)
    return data[playerid].clicks.toString()


}

client.login('token');
```

Comment: does the null propogation operator work?...create a method that reads the data variable passing in the playerid and do the checks in there

Comment: Asynchronous programming is asynchronous

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem isn't that `clicks` is undefined; it's that your `data` variable is undefined.  Check out this code snippet:

```
var data;
var playerid = idd.toString();
fs.readFile("data.json", function(err, data){
  json = JSON.stringify(data);
  data = JSON.parse(json);
})
if(data[playerid].clicks === undefined){ // <-- BOOM
```

The `var data` declares the variable, and it starts off holding the value `undefined`. You are populating `data` with your `JSON.parse`, but that's happening asynchronously in a callback. Therefore the if statement code runs *before* that data assignment.

You'll want to make sure that you're reading `data` *after* it has been populated by putting your code in the callback or using Promises and awaiting the asynchronous file read.

Here's an example of how you can use an async function (keeping in mind that the caller of this function also has to await it):

```
async function clickeridoo(idd){
  const playerid = idd.toString();
  const fileContents = await fs.promises.readFile("data.json");
  const data = JSON.parse(fileContents);
  // TODO: handle case where `data[playerid]` is undefined
  data[playerid].clicks = (data[playerid].clicks || 0) + 1;
  await fs.promises.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify(data));
  return data[playerid].clicks.toString()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know you have an Object, `obj`, that is defined but the property is not, then `obj.prop === undefined` is a valid test that will not throw an Error. If you are not sure that the Object is defined then you must do like: `typeof obj === 'undefined'`. If your variable in question is an argument or is declared but not defined, like `let test;` you can also just test for `test === undefined`. If the variable in question is never defined at all, then you should do like `typeof test === 'undefined'`. Your issue is really resolved by `@Jacob`s answer, it looks like. Of course, this was good to learn for you anyways, so I'm leaving it up.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error's being thrown because `data` is undefined. So you should probably check for that as well. Something like:

```
const clickedDefined = data && data[playerid] && data[playerid].clicks;
```

You can also have a look at the null propagation operator and other ways of doing these checks here: https://ponyfoo.com/articles/null-propagation-operator